# mongodb 3.6.4 for XAMPP 7.2.4 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, xampp

I installed Mongodb through brew on my mac and added the extension to php.ini, but the module does not get loaded after restarting XAMPP.

Mongo is installed:

```
me:~ me$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
git version: d0181a711f7e7f39e60b5aeb1dc7097bf6ae5856
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
allocator: system
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Mongo is running:

```
me:~ me$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.4
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

php.ini has correct extension_dir and extension:

```
me:~ me$ grep mongo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
extension=mongodb.so

me:~ me$ grep extension_dir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
; extension_dir = "./"
; extension_dir = "ext"
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
extension_dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/
```

And the driver is there:

```
me:~ me$ ls /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/
mongodb.so  opcache.so  pdo_dblib.so    pgsql.so
opcache.a   pdo_dblib.a pgsql.a
```

phpinfo() shows the correct extension_dir, but does not load the mongodb module and obviously therefore I can't use it. But xampp does not produce an error after restarting.

If someone has hints, I would be happy to hear so.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is old PHP driving classes, you should use php-mongo package instead of the  php-mongodb.
How to resolve the issue
goto /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin  and run 
sudo pecl install mongo-1.5.8
afer few seconds you will see
Build with Cyrus SASL (MongoDB Enterprise Authentication) support? [no] :
Type no and enter
you will have to change your extension to mongo.so in php.ini